Please help me to identify specific house plant
Not exactly a question about gardening, but this forum seems to be the best bet.
We found the following house plant (fairly common one, as far as I can judge) on the roof top of our apartment building. It is in a sorry condition after having been exposed to direct sunlight for many days without watering. We have brought it home to try to give it second life. But we do not know its name and are not sure how frequently it is supposed to be watered (we did water it generously for the first time, of course). I would appreciate if you could identify it for me.




I believe you have a battle hardened Chlorophytum comosum, also known as a spider plant.  They are great, hardy house plants.
As an aside, the leaves with damaged tips and healthy bases make me wonder if it survived something more than sunshine.


You seem to be right. Thank you for identifying it! It looks like this kind of plants requires frequent watering, at least in summer time. And yes, I agree, some cat could be the reason for its miserable condition (at least, we placed it in such a way to make it unreachable for our cat). Anyway, thank you again!

+1 for the picture, I does indeed say more than thousand words.

As for watering, since the plant is in a saucer I'm guessing you just need to add water to the saucer often enough to prevent it drying out?

@gidds I think that watering method may work, especially if the plant has filled the pot with roots, like these guys like to.  I water mine from the top once a week or a little less often until water starts to seep out of the bottom, and then I empty the saucer when it's collected everything that will be coming out.

To back that up: a characteristic of spider plants is that they have offsets on long stems, and one of those can in fact be seen in the centre of OP's photo.

Spider plants are quite forgiving.  The leaves go pale and dull when they're thirsty, and after a good watering recover within a day.  They're also quite tolerant of generous watering on occasion, so you can give them a soaking before going away
